# How would I get R/W access to a specific memory address using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, gpio

So thinking about how I would make my own hardware/drivers I'm using the GPIO and I know the GPIO uses specific memory banks in a certain range for all hardware in fact, but how would I go about reading and writing them to these memory banks?

Does the USB work in a similar manner?

**P.S** I'm using a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Generally you'd write `peek` and `poke` assembler routines.  You can also use various types of subterfuge to convert an int/long value into an address.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you coding for a particular operating system, or are you writing an embedded program with no o/s?

Comment: USB is altogether a different protocol. GPIO should generally be register mapped. You should be able to read/write memory mapped registers to read/write GPIO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the GPIO (of a raspberry pi) without ``sudo``](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133860/accessing-the-gpio-of-a-raspberry-pi-without-sudo)

Comment: Thanks Rob. I was thinking of first starting it out in Linux and then may by just make my own small OS and go from their.

Comment: Are you using Linux on the RasPi, or just coding straight onto the bare metal?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can also use `Proc interface` to communicate with GPIO. For example if you see this [link](http://www.armadeus.com/wiki/index.php?title=GPIO_Driver#Directly_with_shell_commands_.28through_.2Fproc_.26_.2Fdev_filesystem.29), it shows how GPIO pins can be read or written directly from the shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a system that supports mmap(), https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.os.linux.development.apps/2kiUc-dNa3c discusses using `mmap()` to do this. The summary is that your process will open /dev/mem for reading and writing, and will map your base physical address as the offset into the file (and your addr parameter is whatever virtual address you wish to use).