# Why my app is more colorful in sudo mode?

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, qt5

I have created an app in Qt creator , when i run it in normal mode and sudo mode its colour and icons are different why it is happening , i feel in sudo mode have great look.see below images of both.

[image: Normal Mode]

Above ones is when the app running in normal mode

[image]

This is how it looks in sudo mode,.
I need to run my application in sudo mode because it uses GPIO pins in raspberry pi. But running in sudo mode provide a warning that
`QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root' when running sudo commands`

and my QSettings file is saving in some where in root folder. To avoid this (so that settings file will save in .config folder) i started my app using following command

```
sudo -E ./MyApp
```

So the environment variable is preserved and QSettings are saved in .config folder, but the app looks like normal mode (first picture).

So my question is -How can I preserve the environment variable and same time app looks like sudo mode (second picture)?

i am using c++ in Qtcreator (qt5) for app creation in raspberry pi os

Comment: maybe you are using different shell? e.g. zsh/bash/sh/...

Comment: You don't need `sudo` or root to use GPIO on a Pi: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133860/accessing-the-gpio-of-a-raspberry-pi-without-sudo

Comment: When you use `sudo` you run as a different user (the `root` user), a user with different settings and themes for UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

Hai I got the answer start the app with following command

```
sudo --preserve-env=XDG_RUNTIME_DIR ./MyApp
```

Above command satisfied my both conditions